# what does `expires` in redis `info keyspace` output mean?

Tags: redis

`info keyspace` in Redis gives output like:

```
db0:keys=XXX,expires=YYY
```

What does `expires` mean in this? I'm not able to find any documentation for it? Does it mean the number of keys for which the expiry is set?

Answer (score 14):

Yes, it shows the number of keys that will expire at some point in the future.

Comment: I'd assume this expire time is coming from the redis config. How can we change this to smaller number while the redis instance is running ?

Answer (score 2):

Redis docs on [`info`](https://redis.io/commands/INFO) command states the following:

> The keyspace section provides statistics on the main dictionary of each database. The statistics are the number of keys, and the number of keys with an expiration.
>
> For each database, the following line is added:
>
> dbXXX: keys=XXX,expires=XXX